# Matlab-how to give path to text files in a folder

Tags: matlab, path, directory

I have lots of text files with name file1,file2,file3,.... in a folder called 'text_files'. When I open manually that folder in Matlab directory and perform following it works fine.

```
      textFiles = dir('*.txt');
  for k = 1:length(textFiles);
      filename = textFiles(k).name;
      data = fopen(filename,'r');
      datamatrix=textscan(data, '%f%f','CollectOutput',1);
      data1 = datamatrix{:,1};
      r=data1(:,1);v0=data1(:,2);
      figure(k);
      ph=plot(r,v0);
      xlabel('a'); 
      ylabel('b');

      temp=['fig',num2str(k),'.eps'];
      print(gcf,'-depsc',temp);
      fclose(data);
  end
```

The path to text files in my Mac is `'/Users/ram/group1/sales/text_files'`. What I want to do is instead of manually opening the folder in matlab directory, I want to write a script that does it automatically for me. So, I guess I have to make some change in

```
    textFiles = dir('*.txt');
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full path:

```
src_dir = '/Users/ram/group1/sales/text_files';
textFiles = dir( fullfile( src_dir, '*.txt' ) );
for k = 1:numel(textFiles)
     filename = fullfile( src_dir, textFiles(k).name ); % NOTE the use of src_dir here as well!
     % continue as usuall...
```